# Docker: Linux Worker does not join Overlay network defined by Windows Master. Windows Worker works fine

Tags: linux, windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have the following 3 nodes..

```
C:\Users\yadamu>docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME     STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
4tpray751pk50bl6o6gtbjfq2     YADAMU-DB5   Ready     Active                          20.10.8
xzx0gxu1m0qo59z6gtr4j2i1p *   yadamu-db3   Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.8
x1yh3l6m6k73gytkxx3ipimq4     yadamu-db4   Ready     Active                          20.10.10
```

On yadamu-db3 (Manager), a Windows 11 box, I created an overlay network with

```
docker network create --driver overlay --attachable Y_OVERLAY
```

I then started a set of containers using docker-compose on YADAMU-DB3. They came up as expected and could talk to each other. I then started a second set of containers on YADAMU-DB5, which is also a Windows 11 box using a different docker compose file and they could also talk to each other and to the to containers running on YADAMU-DB5.

I then started a third set of containers using docker compose on YADAMU-DB4, which is running Oracle Enterpise Linux 8. These container can talk to each other but are isolated from the containers running on YADAMU-DB3 and YADAMU-DB5.

All three docker compose files contain the following 'networks' sections

```
networks: 
  YADAMU-NET:
     name: Y_OVERLAY0
     attachable : true
```

However when I run docker-compose on the linux box I see

```
C:\Development\YADAMU\docker\dockerfiles\swarm\YADAMU-DB4>docker-compose up -d
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Creating network "Y_OVERLAY" with the default driver
Creating volume "YADAMU_01-SHARED" with default driver
```

and when I list the networks I see

```
C:\Development\YADAMU\docker\dockerfiles\swarm\YADAMU-DB4>docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
b87206cfac4c   Y_OVERLAY         bridge    local
393beef01a7f   bridge            bridge    local
e19e5f965e8d   docker_gwbridge   bridge    local
1b4cbfa566f0   host              host      local
y58mwnbratkj   ingress           overlay   swarm
32a41d9b3d7c   none              null      local
```

Where as when I list the networks on YADAMU-DB5 I see

```
C:\Users\Mark D Drake>docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME        DRIVER    SCOPE
luh9dw47k5a1   Y_OVERLAY   overlay   swarm
y58mwnbratkj   ingress     overlay   swarm
8fd8ef298f47   nat         nat       local
dce21ec8e1ae   none        null      local
```

So it appears the on the LINUX box it has not resolved Y_OVERLAY as the overlay network defined by the swarm manager.

Any ideas what I'm missing here..

Note the intent here is not to build a resiliant swarm it's to build a qa environment that can us used for testing interaction between windows and linux hosts on limited hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.. If I down the containers on the linux node, and then promote it to a 'Manager', and then run docker-compose up on the linux node, the contains join the Overlay network...

It's doesn't explain why this did not work with the linux node as a worker, but it means I can move ahead.